# chartJS label on each side of the chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to set up Chart.js in a django app using vertical bars, but I am having trouble using the labels. My data is withing the range [-100;+100] and I would like to be able to show one label on top of the chart and another one at the bottom.

Right now I only manage to put label at the bottom of the chart ..
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aP69T.png)

and would need it to look like that :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5dDF.png)

any idea how to achieve that ?
Raphael

Answer (score 2):

Inside of the options object, add two xAxes scales:

```
scales: {
    xAxes: [{
        display: true,
        position: 'top'
    },{
        display: true,
        position: 'bottom'
    }]
}
```

There are a lot of examples on the [website](http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/) and [github](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/tree/master/samples/scales)